# Problemas con ng-repeat de angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

En mi html muestro de forma dinámica información traída desde un web services y los muestro con `ng-repeat`  quedado de la siguiente manera:

[image: como queda]

a esto le quiero agregar este check numérico para agregar y restar cantidad

[image: check]

pero no encuentro la manera de asociar el check a cada objeto dentro del array, es decir que me muestre el precio a cada uno que corresponda, hasta el momento toma el precio del primer valor y al sumar se suman todos, lo mismo al restar.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<ion-list class="text-left" style="padding-left:1px;">
  <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="co in coffe" type="item-text-wrap" href="">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h2 style="color:#878787;"><b>{{co.producto}}</b></h2>
    <div style="width:250px;">
      <h5 style="color:#878787;">{{co.descripcion}}</h5>
    </div>
    <h4 style="color:#878787;">{{co.calorias}}</h4>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-right" style="width:90px">
      <h-number value="test.count"  min="1" max="5" step="1" change="onNumberChanged(co.precio)"></h-number>
      <div class="precio">
        ${{total}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Intente poner un `id` y `for` pero no funciono! :c

en controlador la cosa esta así para no confundir:

```
 $scope.test = {};
 $scope.test.count = 1;

 $scope.onNumberChanged = function(valor){
   var numero = parseInt(valor);
   $scope.total = numero * $scope.test.count
 }

 HernannMovil.Getcafe({

   id_servicio: id

 },function(response){
   console.log(response);
   $scope.coffe = response;
 });
```

Primero defino las variables, luego creo la funcion `onNumberChanged`
   y por ultimo consumo los datos con `getCofe` que trae lo que esta en el array de la imagen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para una respuesta mas concreta sería bueno ver el codigo de tu controlador, pero a simple vista y teniendo en cuenta el comentario que haces en la respuesta de Fernado Forcen, asumo que tu variable `$scope.total` esta declarada en algun punto en el controlador y no es una propiedad de tus objetos `co` incluidos en tu arreglo `coffe`. Es decir que estas mostrando `$scope.total` en todos los casos, como una especie de variable global del controlador, cuando deberias mostrar `co.total`; realizar la suma del objeto en cuestion y poner el resultado de esa sumatoria en una propiedad del mismo objeto en cuestion, y en vez de poner en tu vista html `{{total}}` deberia verse como `{{co.total}}`
En el `ng-click` puedes mandar como parámetro el item en cuestion para realizar los calculos; seria algo como `ng-click="realizarSuma(co)"` de esa forma ya en la funcion haces lo correpondiente para afectar a ese item en especial.

Comment: ok agregare mi controller code

Comment: en efecto lo que te comentaba sobre la variable `$scope.total` esta en el ámbito global del controlador, por lo que si afectas a esa variable, todas las partes de tu html donde tengas `{{total}}` van a cambiar, para que se produzca el resultado que creo que buscas, lo conveniente seíra agregarle a cada objeto dentro de `$scope.coffe` la propiedad `total` para que sea esa propiedad la que afectes en la suma y a su vez la que muestres en la vista html

Comment: sería llamar a suma primero como `ng-click="realizarSuma(co)"` despues en tu controlador declaras dicha funcion `$scope.realizarSuma = function(item){ item.total = item.valor * $scope.test.count; };` .... y en la vista como vas a tener `{{co.total}}` deberia cambiar de forma automatica el resultado solo de ese elemento en el que se esta haciendo click... no soy muy bueno explicando las cosas espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: esta perfet! funciono, es decir muestra sus precios correspondientes pero el checkbox al estar en el ng-repeat se duplica según el lenght y no tiene propiedad distinta, es el mismo en todo, ej: si sumo el primero se suman todos los demaces y eso tengo que solucionarlo. :0 estoy casi casi

Comment: Como es que construyes tu directiva que maneja la etiqueta `h-number`?

Comment: con ionic-number-picker pero creo que ya descubrí quien es el encargado de marcar la diferencia y ese es value="" como tiene de valor test.count a todos se les carga el mismo valor, por eso si muevo uno se mueven todos, ahora tengo que lograr que no tenga el mismo valor pero que sí sea 1

Comment: Entiendo, crees que sería conveniente quiza agregar la propiedad `cantidad` a cada elemento de `coffe` y asi la multiplicacion sería con propiedades del mismo objeto? y en la vista ponerle el valor al check como `value="co.cantidad"` .... no he tenido la oportunidad de trabajar con **ionic-number-picker** pero quiza podria funcionar asi.

Comment: dices agregar una tabla que se llame cantidad y asignarle el valor 1 a todos, lo recibo lo transformo a entero y ese lo asigno en value ? mmm creo que eso podría funcionar,

Comment: Algo asi, como se le agregó la propiedad `total` a cada elemento asi mismo se le agregaria la propiedad `cantidad` y luego ya se manipula en la funcion de la suma `item.total = item.valor * item.cantidad;`

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que el problema puede ser que están usando `co.precio` en lugar de `co.numero` que parece ser tu identificador. En cualquier caso es mejor que utilices ng-click en lugar de gestionarlo con eventos nativos. Solo tendrías que invocar tu método con el objeto o con el identificador del mismo:

`ng-click='onNumberChanged(co.numero)` o `ng-click='onNumberChanged(co)`

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: yo mando el precio porque en la function lo transformo a int ,lo multiplico por test.count  que es 1 ++  y el resultado lo guardo en $scope.total y ese valor lo muestro como ${{total}}. al ir sumando o restando automaticamente me va mostrando el precio

Comment: mmm, no se si lo he entendido muy bien. En cualquier caso, si usas la segunda aproximación `ng-click='onNumberChanged(co)` ya tendrás el objeto completo en tu Controller y podrás sacar la información que necesites de el.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes modificar tú método change="onNumberChanged(co.precio)" de la siguiente manera :

$scope.onNumberChanged = function($index, cantidad){

/*
Recorres tú array hasta encontrar el elemento a ser modificado, una vez    encontrado lo modificas realizando el calculo de precio * cantidad,
es importante que le agregues el atributo total a tú objeto, por data binding
la actualización va ser refrescada en tú vista.
*/

}

Espero te sea de utilidad.